# calculate nested field collection with computed field

Tags: entities

I have this complex collection field in content type

collection field "parent"

---

```
 - computed field "a" (sum all computed field "b" listed in collection field "a")
 - collection field "a" (unlimited value)
 *******************************************
               - - computed field "b" (sum of "Result" listed in collection field "b")
               - - collection field "b" (unlimited value)
               ********************************************
                                    - - - num1
                                    - - - num2
                                    - - - Result computed field (sum num1 + num2)
```

so how can i do this or what the computed code which must write in each computed field for each one